# add parent key to array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Hola my friends out there,
 i am looking to transfor array of objects `res` from this:

```
[{
    "Key1": 1,
    "Key2": "James",
},
{
    "Key1: 2,
    "Key2": "John",
}]
```

to this (basically adding a parent key to each object in the array):

```
[{"ParentKey":
   {
    "Key1" : 1,
    "Key2" : James"
   }
  },
 {"ParentKey":
   {
    "Key1" : 2,
    "Key2" : "John"
   }
 }]
```

possibly without using a bruteforce approach (for loop) but maybe lodash?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

With plain Javascript, you could iterate with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and assign a new object.

```js
var res = [{ Key1: 1, Key2: "James", }, { Key1: 2, Key2: "John", }];

res.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    aa[i] = { ParentKey: a };
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

As an alternative, you could iterate with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and assign the result array to a variable.

```js
var res = [{ Key1: 1, Key2: "James", }, { Key1: 2, Key2: "John", }],
    padded = res.map(function (a) {
        return { ParentKey: a };
    });

console.log(padded);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to transform each element in the array.

```
_.map([
    {"Key1": 1,"Key2": "James",},
    {"Key1": 2,"Key2": "John",}], 
    function(v) {
        return {"ParentKey":v}
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Array.map` `function` to get the desired result.

Here is the snippet.

```js
var array = [{"Key1": 1,"Key2": "James",}, {"Key1": 2,"Key2": "John",}];
var result = array.map(function(item){
  return {"parentKey": item};
});

console.log(result);
```